# JavaScript: Climb back up dom tree from within iframe

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following code:

```
<div id="hello">
    <iframe stc="foo/bar.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Contents of iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get the div with id "hello"?

If all this was on the same page I would do something like:

```
document.getElementById('foo').parentNode;
```

Note: I can't use jQuery for this project. Also I can't select by id because I don't know what the id of that parent would be. If it would have always been foo then I could have done:

```
parent.document.getElementById('foo')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe

Comment: No, that question is about the opposite problem.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the iframe or the parent page?

Comment: If you're trying to do it from the iframe, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877237/target-parent-div-containing-iframe-from-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Can you select element by class name?  If so, here's a way of doing that:  http://www.anyexample.com/webdev/javascript/javascript_getelementsbyclass_function.xml